# Apache rewrite rules for Angular site using multiple domains on same machine

Tags: angularjs, apache, .htaccess

I have multiple domains I point at the same machine (some with subdomains), the main site is rendered using AngularJS. I have a new domain `www.newsite.com` to add in, but I want this new domain to point to a page on the main site, i.e. `http://example.co/#/newsite`, is there a clever way to do this with an apache rewrite rule? I also don't have html5 mode working, so fixing that so I could get rid of the `#` in the site URLs might be nice.

my current setup is like so:

main site:

- located at /var/www/html/site, web address http://example.co

  `000-default.conf` file:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>

      ServerName example.co
      ServerAlias www.example.co
      ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

blog site:

- located at /var/www/html/site/blog, web address: http://blog.example.co

  `blog.conf` file:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName blog.example.co

      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site/blog

      <Directory />
              Options FollowSymLinks
              AllowOverride None
      </Directory>

      <Directory /var/www/html/site/blog/>
              Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Order allow,deny
              allow from all
      </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

.org site:

- same location /var/www/html/site, web address: http://example.org

  `org.conf` file:

  ```
  <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.example.org
      ServerAlias example.org

      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site

      <Directory /var/www/html/site/>
              Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Order allow,deny
              allow from all
      </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

---

So I think what I need to do is create another `.conf` file, like the following:

newsite site:

- also located at /var/www/html/site, but the web address is http://example.co/#/newsite

  `newsite.conf` file:

  ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerName www.newexample.com
      ServerAlias newexample.com

      DocumentRoot /var/www/html/site

      <Directory /var/www/html/site/>
              Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
              AllowOverride All
              Order allow,deny
              allow from all
      </Directory>

  </VirtualHost>
  ```

And then make a `.htaccess` file for the main(?) site, that allows any traffic coming from `newexample.com` to be directed to `http://example.co/#/newsite`?

Comment: Not sure why you don't just let your angular router set the final part of the path using `otherwise({redirecTo:...})`. Just check  `location.host` before setting it

Comment: that works! good call, want to submit an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the configuration in your angular router for the last part of the path.

Just check `location.host` before setting the `otherwise` redirect default of the app